# Why am I getting a typescript compile error with Aurelia and Gulp?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, aurelia

I am receiving the following error messages when running a gulp watch or gulp build command from VS Code.   This is an Aurelia application running in node.

```
typings\modules\aurelia-dependency-injection\index.d.ts(190,82): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
typings\modules\aurelia-dependency-injection\index.d.ts(190,108): error TS1109: Expression expected.
typings\modules\aurelia-dependency-injection\index.d.ts(190,138): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

--au help output
`No Aurelia project found Global aurelia-cli v1.0.2`

--npm version
`6.9.0`

Comment: Well, from the errors, it looks like you are missing a { or ;. Fix that and you are good. Without the code you are trying to "gulp", all this means nothing.

Comment: update your cli globaly (with `npm i -g aurelia cli`), then create anew project and copy your `src` folder to the newly created app.